# Alternative to make an action when pressing/realising a button, android

Tags: java, android, android-button, ontouchlistener

I want to make an application with 9 buttons for android 4.0, I need each of the buttons to call a method when *pressed* and another method when *released*.

I'm kind of surprised there's not a really straight-forward method to accomplish what I just described but thanks to some questions and answers I read on stackoverflow I managed to accomplish what I need by adding a listener **in each of the buttons**, as shown for one of the buttons in the next code.

```
buttonUp.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            buttonUpPressed();
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            buttonUpReleased();
        }                
        return true;
    }           
});
```

I want to know if there's an alternative to accomplish this behavior without having to add a listener for **every** button. I see that as a waste of resources and a lot of coding. I can't imagine if I eventually have to add more buttons.

So any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implements your class with OnTouchListener

```
Button a,b;
        Button[] bArray = {a,b};
        for (int i = 0; i < bArray.length; i++) {
            bArray[i].setOnTouchListener(this)
        }
```

after that add unimplemented method

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.button1:

                    break;

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
        return false;
    }
```

i hope you'll like my logic :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the buttons to an array or ArrayList and then define a listener field in your class.

```
OnTouchListener oclButtons = new OnTouchListener(...);
```

Then you can add the same listener to all the Buttons in the ArrayList.

```
for (Button b : listOfButtons) {
    b.setOnTouchListener(oclButtons);
}
```

An alternative to setting IDs for each Button is to get/set tags (since each view needs a unique ID). Your listener can determine which button was touched by using v.getTag().

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the logic works but in this particular case adding OnClickListeners is not useful for me since i need to carry out an action when the button is pressed and another action when it's released. A click is considered to be as such only after releasing the button :)